# Extract YEAR from date and group it

Tags: php, date, grouping, extract

i have a small problem.

```
$fetch_years=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT date, YEAR(shift.date) as year FROM shift");
while($years = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_years))
{
    echo ' '.$years['date'].' <br/> '.$year.' <br/><br/>';
```

I try to extract the year from the date field and group it. 
The part '.$years['date'].' 
 and missing group by is only for the test

That's my result:

```
2016-10-13
2017

2017-11-04
2017

2017-11-10
2017
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the echo command, you take `$years['date']`, which comes from the query results and `$year`, which comes from... ?

Instead of `$year`, do `$years['year']` to get the results form your query.

```
echo ' '.$years['date'].' <br/> '.$years['year'].' <br/><br/>';
```

For your question, you should have put tag PHP as well.